# Copying Array Using Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create a copy of an array by only accessing an array using pointer arithmetic. This is my function

```
 int* arrCopy(int *a, int size){
    int *b = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *(b+(sizeof(int)*i)) = *(a+(sizeof(int)*i));
    }
    return b;
}
```

When I print the array it shows that the copied array is filled with the repeating of the first two values in the original array. So if the original array was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then arrcopy would be [1, 2, 1 ,2 ,1] and I can't figure out why.

Comment: When you add one to pointer, it is incremented by the size of the object pointed at.  It's one of the reasons you need to get the pointer type right.  It's easier to read and write `b[i] = a[i];` — if you don't use `memmove()` or `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```
int * arrCopy( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    int *b = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *( b + i ) = *( a + i );
    }

    return b;
}
```

Or you could check whether the memory was successfully allocated.

```
int * arrCopy( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    int *b = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( b != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            *( b + i ) = *( a + i );
        }
    }

    return b;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * arrCopy( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    int *b = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( b != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            *( b + i ) = *( a + i );
        }
    }           

    return b;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int *b = arrCopy( a, N );

    if ( b != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", b[i] );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( b );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

As for your code then for example this expression

```
*(b+(sizeof(int)*i))
```

is invalid. It selects the element of the array b equivalent to

```
b[sizeof(int)*i]
```

So for example when `i` is equal to `1` and `sizeof( int )` equal to `4` then instead of getting the element `b[1]` you are getting the element `b[4]`.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. **The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))).** Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).